# Aggregate time series data on weekly basis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe that consists of 3 years of data and two columns `remaining useful life` and  `predicted remaining useful life`.

I am aggregating `rul` and `pred_rul` of 3 years data for each machineID for the maximum date they have. The original dataframe looks like this-

```
              rul   pred_diff   machineID   datetime
10476749    870    312.207825   408      2021-05-25 00:00:00
11452943    68     288.517578   447      2023-03-01 12:00:00
12693829    381    273.159698   493      2021-09-16 16:00:00
3413787     331    291.326416   133      2022-10-26 12:00:00
464093       77    341.506195   19       2023-10-10 16:00:00
... ... ... ... ...
11677555    537    310.586090   456      2022-04-07 00:00:00
2334804     551    289.307129   92       2021-09-04 20:00:00
5508311     35     293.721771   214      2023-01-06 04:00:00
12319704    348    322.199219   479      2021-11-11 20:00:00
4777501      87    278.089417   186      2021-06-29 12:00:00
1287421 rows × 4 columns
```

And I am aggregating it based on this code-

```
y_test_grp = y_test.groupby('machineID').agg({'datetime':'max', 'rul':'mean', 'pred_diff':'mean'})[['datetime','rul', 'pred_diff']].reset_index()
```

which gives the following output-

```
    machineID   datetime    rul         pred_diff
0   1   2023-10-03 20:00:00 286.817681  266.419401
1   2   2023-11-14 00:00:00 225.561953  263.372531
2   3   2023-10-25 00:00:00 304.736237  256.933351
3   4   2023-01-13 12:00:00 204.084899  252.476066
4   5   2023-09-07 00:00:00 208.702431  252.487156
... ... ... ... ...
495 496 2023-10-11 00:00:00 302.445285  298.836798
496 497 2023-08-26 04:00:00 281.601613  263.479885
497 498 2023-11-28 04:00:00 292.593906  263.985034
498 499 2023-06-29 20:00:00 260.887529  263.494844
499 500 2023-11-08 20:00:00 160.223614  257.326034
500 rows × 4 columns
```

Since this is `grouped by` on machineID, it is giving just 500 rows which is less. I want to aggregate `rul` and `pred_rul` on weekly basis such that for each machineID I get 52weeks*3years=156 rows. I am not able to identify which function to use for taking 7 days as interval and aggregating `rul` and `pred_rul` on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
pd.groupby(['machineID', pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='7D')]).mean()
```